# How can I fulfill my need to get existing data and save if available in the create method of nested serializers using Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**serializers.py**

```
class Product_Serializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_id = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('product_id','product_name',)


class Clientpost_Serializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    billing_method = Billingmethod_Serializers()
    product = Product_Serializers(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        billing_method_data = validated_data.pop('billing_method')
        product_data = validated_data.pop('product')
        billing_method = Billing_Method.objects.create(**billing_method_data)
        validated_data['billing_method'] = billing_method
        client = Client.objects.create(**validated_data)
        product = [Product.objects.create(**product_data) for product_data in product_data]
        client.product.set(product)
        return client



    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        billing_method_data = validated_data.pop('billing_method')
        billing_method = instance.billing_method

        instance.currency = validated_data.get('currency', instance.currency)
        instance.currency_type = validated_data.get('currency_type', instance.currency_type)
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.street_address = validated_data.get('street_address', instance.street_address)
        instance.city = validated_data.get('city', instance.city)
        instance.state = validated_data.get('state', instance.state)
        instance.country = validated_data.get('country', instance.country)
        instance.pincode = validated_data.get('pincode', instance.pincode)
        instance.industry = validated_data.get('industry', instance.industry)
        instance.company_size = validated_data.get('company_size', instance.company_size)
        instance.client_name = validated_data.get('client_name', instance.client_name)
        instance.contact_no = validated_data.get('contact_no', instance.contact_no)
        instance.mobile_no = validated_data.get('mobile_no', instance.mobile_no)
        instance.email_id = validated_data.get('email_id', instance.email_id)
        instance.client_logo = validated_data.get('client_logo', instance.client_logo)
        instance.client_code = validated_data.get('client_code', instance.client_code)
        instance.save()

        billing_method.billing_name = billing_method_data.get('billing_name', billing_method.billing_name)
        billing_method.save()

        product = validated_data.get('product')

        for prod in product:
            product_id = prod.get('product_id', None)
            if product_id:
                product_data = Product.objects.get(product_id=product_id, product=instance)
                product_data.product_name = prod.get('product_name', product_data.product_name)
                product_data.save()
            else:
                Product.objects.create(product=instance, **prod)

        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('client_id','currency','currency_type','billing_method','first_name',...)
```

When I Tired to do POST and PUT method it is getting posted and updated successfully. But it is getting created every time when I do POST, as I have given unique=True so it is throwing the product is already exist. But I do'nt need to create it each time, if it is already available it needs to be saved in the nested model field. Is that possible ?

I tried and I couldn't able to figure it out, please help me to solve the issue. It would be a life saver if I could get any answer.

**Views.py**

```
class Clientlist(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (CustomRenderer,)
    parser_classes = [parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.FormParser]

    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        clients = models.Client.objects.all()
        serializer = serializers.Clientpost_Serializers(clients, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = serializers.Clientpost_Serializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class ClientDetail(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (CustomRenderer,)
    parser_classes = [parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.FormParser]

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return models.Client.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except models.Client.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        client = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = serializers.Client_Serializers(client)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        client = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = serializers.Clientpost_Serializers(client, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        client = self.get_object(pk)
        client.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: What view are you using for dealing with GET and POST API?

Comment: @Davide Lu I have updated my views in the questions,please check and let me know if you need anything to solve my issue.

Comment: In general, POST is for create, and PUT is for Update. And so if you want to update some object that already exists, then you need to use PUT or PATCH method, not POST.